# How to set a friendly name using native API IOS/Android in MFP server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

As documented in the link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html , The WL.Device class in MFP JavaScript client API has methods setFriendlyName/getFriendlyName for setting/getting friendly name to/from MFP server.

However these to methods are not there in the MFP iOS/Android native API (i.e. class WLDevice in both platforms).

So, is there any way I can set friendly name using iOS/Android native API?

Answer (score 3):

No, setting friendly name is only included in JavaScript. You could always make a portion of your app Web and set the friendly name there and run the rest of your app in Native.

If you want this to be a native API you may submit a feature request: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe

Comment: Hi Chevy, Is there any other way like 1)Do we have rest end point to add the friendly name or 2) can we add this through adapter.

Comment: @chevy, can you let me know what is the syntax for calling this method? I try with  WL.Device.SetDeviceDisplayName("My Device"); but not able to set deviceName